# Как сделать чтобы комманду бота могли использовать те роли у которых есть разрешение

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Я создаю бота в дискорде с помощью библиотеки Discord.py и яя создал команду на кик:

```
@client.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True )
async def kick( ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None ):
   await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

Надо чтобы эту команду могли использовать только те роли у которых есть право на кик сейчас это могут только администраторы,
как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, kick_members=True)
```

или

```py
@client.command()
async def kick( ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None ):
    # роль, которая имеет право кикнуть
    can_kick_role_id = 34885763857356345
    can_kick_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=can_kick_role_id)
    if can_kick_role in ctx.author.roles:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
```